# Transferring the correct value to my json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this function, which displays the items that the user has added to their cart.

```
function _getmycart(arr) {

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var t;

    t = "<div class='items'><img src='" + serverURL() + "/images/" +
      arr[i].itemImage + "' class='image'><div class='deletebtn' 
    id = 'deletebtn"+ arr[i].itemID +"' > < input type = 'image'
    src = 'images/deletebtn.jpg'
    class = 'deletebtn' > < /div><div 
    class = 'itemName' > < b > "+arr[i].itemName+" < /b></div > < div
    class = 'itemID' > Item ID: " +arr[i].itemID+" < /div><div 
    class = 'itemSize' > < b > "+ arr[i].itemSize+" < /b></div > < div
    class = 'itemPrice' > $ "+ arr[i].itemPrice +" < /div></div > "

    $('#mycartitems').append(t);

    const sum = arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc + Number(el.itemPrice), 0);
    $('#totals').html("Total S$" + sum);

    $('#deletebtn' + arr[i].itemID).bind("click", {
        id: arr[i].itemID
      },
      function(event) {
        var data = event.data;
        deleteitem(data.id);
      });

  }
}
```

and i'm using this to send the `itemID` and `email` to my php.

```
function deleteitem(itemID) {

  var url = serverURL() + "/deletemycartitems.php";
  var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
  var JSONObject = {
    "email": email,
    "itemID": itemID,


  };

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    data: JSONObject,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(arr) {
      _getmycart(arr);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Failed");
    }

  });

}
```

I cant seem to get the correct itemID, where did i go wrong?

Comment: IDs should not contain `"` quotes, I'm pretty sure, and you also shouldn't use numeric-indexed IDs like that, you might use `data-` attributes instead

Comment: can i get an example?